# How to run steam through "TCP over SSL tunnel"?

Tags: steam

I'm from the country with the worst internet connection (no joke, research was done in 2020). So I'm tunneling a zoom package and I can't seem to run Steam through the proxy I create. How do I achieve this? I just want to download content using a socks proxy tunnel.

edit: more context- tbh I don't know any other way I can use a data package dedicated to video conferencing to download a game. internet connections work really different in my country. the issue is there aren't any admin restrictions on my laptop but the one from **ISS**, I can use **Zoom** app but nothing else. So I'm using TCP over SSL tunnel to access internet. still I can't download anything from **Steam** with this.

Comment: I think this may be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Downloads always happen through TCP (because the alternative, UDP does not guarantee that your package will arrive, unlike TCP), and SSL is an encryption protocol that's now considered insecure and has been deprecated since 2015 and replaced by TLS. Why do you think that using SSL would be any faster than whatever it is that Steam is currently using? And is a faster speed really worth risking losing your account to some random hacker?

Comment: I updated the question & thank you for being informant on the subject I had no idea. Still idk how to use a TLS tunnel so I don't know how that's gonna help me if TLS can't help me run steam either